# C Programming - Passing an Undeclared String to a Function (Memory Allocation)

Tags: c, string, memory, memory-management

I have a question relating to passing an `undeclared String` to a `Function`.

The code below compiles and works correctly (*in that the string is correctly printed)*. I'm trying to understand the details of how the code works with respect to memory allocation *(does the compiler generate a Temporary variable from the "String" and actually pass that to the Function?)*.

Normally I would declare a `char` array to hold the String and then pass that to the function - that makes sense in terms of memory allocation.

I'm specifically looking to see if there are any gotchas with respect to memory leaks if strings are passed directly as per the program below (e.g. a long running program passing lots of Strings to a Log - does each string pass create some sort of new string variable whose memory is never released etc).

Code - Compiles in Visual Studio 2013

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Function Declaration
int MyFunction(char *SomeString);


int main(void)
{
    MyFunction("MyString");
    return 0;
}


//Function Code
int MyFunction(char *SomeString) {
    printf("Passed String: %s \n", SomeString);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler creates a string literal, and when you call `MyFunction("MyString")` the pointer to that string literal is passed to the function. The `"Mystring"` string will exist as long as your program runs.

This:

```
MyFunction("MyString");
```

is more or less equivalent to

```
static char *mystring = "MyString";
MyFunction(mystring);
```

Answer (score 3):

> *I have a question relating to passing an `undeclared String` to a `Function`.*

No, you're not passing an *undeclared* string here. In your case,

```
  MyFunction("MyString");
```

`"MyString"` is called a *string literal* and can be considered an unnamed variable. Usually, this resides on the non-modifiable memory.

The memory allocation is handled by the compiler itself during the compilation time and hence you need not to be bothered about the memory allocation and deallocation part.

Answer (score 2):

There are no memory leaks in your program. The type of a string literal *N* characters long is `const char[N+1]` (the `+1` is for the NUL terminator). In effect, your program has a hidden global object of type `const char[9]`, which contains the characters `M` `y` `S` `t` `r` `i` `n` `g` `NUL`. You refer to this object using the literal `"MyString"`.

When passed to `MyFunction`, a temporary automatic object of type `char *` is created which points to the first character in that array (this is a standard conversion which happens with all arrays). That temporary is destroyed again when the call ends. The memory for the array itself is not dynamically allocated and so it cannot leak.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning for OP that whenever an array variable is used in an expression it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Sir, I do have a doubt, If in a function `fun()` we declare a `char *c="Some string"`. Then would that `"Some string"` would still be a *hiddden global object*  and will be stored in  *initialized read-only data segment* or would be *auto* and stored in *stack*?

Comment: @ARBY Where *exactly* it ends up allocated and stored (physically) depends on the compiler and its optimisations. But from the language point of view, it's an array of `const char`s with static storage duration - so global.

Answer (score 0):

A function argument is considered as an initializer of the corresponding function parameter. You can imagine this function call

```
MyFunction("MyString");
```

the following way

```
int MyFunction( /*char *SomeString*/) {
    char *SomeString = "MyString";
    printf("Passed String: %s \n", SomeString);
    return 0;
}
```

The string literal used in the function call has type of character array `char[9]` and has the static storage duration. That is when the compiler compiles the program then it places each string literal used in the program in the static memory as a character array.
In the function call the character array that corresponds to the string literal is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character.  That is the compiler creates a temporary object of type `char *` that has value equal to the address of the first character of the string literal (static array) and pushes it on the stack as an argument of the function.
So more precisely the function call

```
MyFunction("MyString");
```

can be imagine like

```
char *tmp = "MyString";
MyFunction( tmp );
//...

int MyFunction( /*char *SomeString*/) {
    char *SomeString = tmp;
    printf("Passed String: %s \n", SomeString);
    return 0;
}
```